# Firefox doesn't align images correctly

Tags: css, firefox, html

I'm trying to make a little gallery of some school works I've done in my animation class. I want to put 3 images on each line and they are all in divs because I did onion skin wrapping for a dropshadow on them. Unfortunately this makes them all just stick together in two lines across the page. But I want them specifically formatted so I tried to wrap a div of 480px wide around each set of 3. In IE this works great and it looks perfect. However in firefox it does this

[image]

I can't figure out why it is putting that one left aligned on the second line and therefore screwing up the order of the rest. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ryan Merl's Portfolio</title>
<style type='text/css'>
    * {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    body {
        background-color:#333333;
        background-image: url('images/head.png');
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }
    a {
        color:#333333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
        color:#000000;
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    div.main {
        width: 800px;
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #000000;
        height: 1000px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    img.thumb {

    }
    .wrap1, .wrap2, .wrap3 {
        display:inline-table;
        /* \*/display:block;/**/
    }
    .wrap1 {
        float:left;
        background:url('images/shadow.gif') right bottom no-repeat;
    }
    .wrap2 {
        background:url('images/corner_bl.gif') left bottom no-repeat;
    }
    .wrap3 {
        padding:0 4px 4px 0;
        background:url('images/corner_tr.gif'   ) right top no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="doc/css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/adapter/shadowbox-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="glossy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

Shadowbox.loadSkin('classic', 'src/skin');
Shadowbox.loadLanguage('en', 'src/lang');
Shadowbox.loadPlayer(['flv', 'html','img', 'swf'], 'src/player');

window.onload = function(){
    Shadowbox.init();
};

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <center><div class='main'>
        <img src='images/theantistudio.png' /><br /><br />

        <img src='images/gallery.png' /><br />
        <div style='text-align:center;width:480px;'>
            <div class="wrap1">
                <div class="wrap2">
                    <div class="wrap3">
                        <a href='video/rmerl_particle_fire.flv' rel='shadowbox'><img class='thumb' src='thumbs/thumb_fire.png' /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap1">
                <div class="wrap2">
                    <div class="wrap3">
                        <a href='video/rmerl_firework.flv' rel='shadowbox'><img class='thumb' src='thumbs/thumb_firework.png' /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap1">
                <div class="wrap2">
                    <div class="wrap3">
                        <a href='video/rmerl_fountain.flv' rel='shadowbox'><img class='thumb' src='thumbs/thumb_fountain.png' /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div style='text-align:center;width:480px;'>
            <div class="wrap1">
                <div class="wrap2">
                    <div class="wrap3">
                        <a href='video/rmerl_logo.flv' rel='shadowbox'><img class='thumb' src= 'thumbs/thumb_logo.png' /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap1">
                <div class="wrap2">
                    <div class="wrap3">  
                        <a href='video/rmerl_rocket_ship.flv' rel='shadowbox'><img class='thumb' src='thumbs/thumb_rocket.png' /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap1">
                <div class="wrap2">
                    <div class="wrap3">
                        <a href='video/rmerl_solar_system.flv' rel='shadowbox'><img class='thumb' src='thumbs/thumb_solar_system.png' /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div style='text-align:center;width:480px;'>
            <div class="wrap1">
                <div class="wrap2">
                    <div class="wrap3">
                        <a href='video/rmerl_space_ship.flv' rel='shadowbox'><img class='thumb' src='thumbs/thumb_space_ship.png' /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap1">
                <div class="wrap2">
                    <div class="wrap3">
                        <a href='video/rmerl_still_life.flv' rel='shadowbox'><img class='thumb' src='thumbs/thumb_still_life.png' /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap1">
                <div class="wrap2">
                    <div class="wrap3">
                        <a href='video/rmerl_walkthrough.flv' rel='shadowbox'><img class='thumb' src='thumbs/thumb_walkthrough.png' /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: would be nice if you scaled your image down a bit if you're going to link it inline.

Comment: Remember that we don't have your images... so for us to look at this, you'll have to put width and height attributes on your image tags.

Comment: Scaled down the picture to 512*384.

Comment: My best guess however is that your row divs should be set to overflow:auto and clear:both, and get rid of the brs.

Comment: Is anyone else confused by the "two lines" and "left aligned"? I see 4 lines, right aligned on the second row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your second image may be slightly taller than your third. So your floated second line is only floating back until it hits the second image. Either set your image or wrap1 heights, or add style="clear:both" to the break tags between lines.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see your picture, but based on your description it sounds like you're not clearing the floats. You have a br after each block of three images in a div, so adding the following CSS will clear the floats and show three in a row.

```
br { clear: both; }
```

Comment: he could do that on the parent div of .wrap1 - the br is entirely extraneous

Comment: Very true. There's also no need for the inline styles on the parent div to .wrap1.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if there is not enough width on a specified "line", it will drop down to the next line.  Try making the window as wide as possible (click n drag) and see if this is the issue.